# Combining two conditions in numpy (column-wise)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have got the following table

```
   A    B     C <br/>
1  5  True    10<br/>
2  6  False   2<br/>
3  1  True    5<br/>
```

Now I would like to create a new column `D` which is set to TRUE when column `A` is larger than 5 and `B` is TRUE.
The following command does not work:

```
df['D'] = FALSE
df[['A', 'B','D']].apply(lambda x: x['D']=TRUE if x['A']>5 & x['B']==TRUE else FALSE, axis=1)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I assume as you write sth about `df` that also `pandas should be tagged... And please comment code as such. And to be complete: Please provide sth useful runnable, perhaps a definition of your dataframe, so that it can be copy/pasted for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
import numpy as np
df['D'] = (df['A']>5) & (df['B']==True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A   B       C    D
0   5   True    10  False
1   6   False   2   False
2   1   True    5   False
```

**Additional**

If your desired column is not boolean then you can use `np.where`:

```
df['D'] = np.where((df['A']>5) & (df['B']==True), 'TRUE','FALSE')
```

Comment: if the desired output is boolean anyway, why do one need `np.where` then? shouldn't `df['D'] = (df['A']>5) & (df['B']==True)` be enough here?